# SOAP redirect to another web service

Tags: c#, wcf, redirect, soap

I am consuming a SOAP Web Service through a client auto generated with the "Add Service Reference..." wizard in Visual Studio.

XML configuration on web.config like this :

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceBinding" allowCookies="true" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="52428800" maxStringContentLength="52428800" maxArrayLength="52428800" maxBytesPerRead="52428800" maxNameTableCharCount="52428800" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

I also pass an authorization header, and the service I call is in https
All working

Later I had to implement a redirect to another site without touching the client code
Server side then I made a 307 and changed the RedirectLocation of the ttpContext.Current.Response

The call to the other site is made but does not carry the authorization header
Situation: error - 401 not authorized

I also tried to make the other site in http, so that it is not necessary to pass the authorization header
With this XML configuration on web.config :

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceBinding" allowCookies="true" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="52428800" maxStringContentLength="52428800" maxArrayLength="52428800" maxBytesPerRead="52428800" maxNameTableCharCount="52428800" />
       <security mode="None"> </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Situation : Error because when the call comes back it violates the contract

I can make the second site in http / https but the first site of origin must necessarily be in https

How can I do ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can do it with [multiple endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/multiple-endpoints), with different bindingConfiguration.Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521945/wcf-https-and-multiple-sites-in-iis).